# How to give the push access to github repo without giving the github account credentials?

Tags: github

I wrote the tool which use the one github repo as a cloud storage.

I need to give the write (push) access for this tool to one github repo, but I do not want to use the github user credentials (user name and password), because anyone can use it to logon to github and change the credentials or delete the repo.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate an [OAuth authorization for your specific app](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth_authorizations/#get-or-create-an-authorization-for-a-specific-app-and-fingerprint).

See an [example here](https://gist.github.com/cthiel/4df21cf628cc3a8f1568): it supposed you have [registered you app in your account](https://github.com/settings/applications/new).